# get random no between range without duplicate

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, random

All 
     I want logical help. I have 100 row in database and get all rows random ally without duplication I have used below code.

```
public ArrayList<Rows> getRows(){
    ArrayList<Rows> myRaw=new ArrayList<Rows>();
    Cursor rawCursor=this.db.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(rawCursor.getCount()>0){
        Random rng = new Random();
        rawCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {

             // Ideally just create one instance globally
            ArrayList<Rows> generated = new ArrayList<Raws>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 371; i++)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    Integer next = rng.nextInt(371) + 1;
                    rawCursor.moveToPosition(next);
                    Rows raw=new Raws(rawCursor.getInt(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),rawCursor.getString(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("raw")),rawCursor.getInt(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("fav")));
                    if (!generated.contains(raw))
                    {
                        // Done for this iteration
                        generated.add(raw);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            myRaw=generated;

        } while (rawCursor.moveToNext());
        rawCursor.close();
    }
    return myRaw;
}
```

Thanks All

Comment: What is your question?  i.e. what is wrong with the code you have written?

Comment: any reason not to use `ORDER BY RANDOM()`?

Comment: @RenatoLochetti : Ok I'll but when I ask question and i haven't get proper answer than how can i accept it because other developer may be follow it.

Comment: @MattWhipple Can you explain more about order by RANDOM.

Comment: If you add an `ORDER BY RANDOM()` clause to the original query, the result set will be randomized and you can just iterate over it.  You'd shift responsibility to SQLite which will have internal optimizations beyond what you'd be able to do.  The accepted answer takes care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the database to order the records by some [random number](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random):

```
cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, "random()");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about Collections shuffle?
[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29)

```
public ArrayList<Rows> getRows() {
    ArrayList<Rows> myRaw = new ArrayList<Rows>();
    Cursor rawCursor = this.db.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (rawCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        // get all the rows
        rawCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Rows raw = new Raws(rawCursor.getInt(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")), rawCursor.getString(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("raw")), rawCursor.getInt(rawCursor.getColumnIndex("fav")));
            myRaw.add(raw);
        } while (rawCursor.moveToNext());
        rawCursor.close();
    }
    // shuffle the rows in some kind of random order
    Collections.shuffle(myRaw);
    return myRaw;
}
```

The answer provided by @CL. could be a better option, but the main difference is that the `shuffle` method has an option to provide your own `Random` object, this means that you can [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) the random.

```
//Random with seed;
Random r = new Random(68498493);
Collections.shuffle(myRaw, r);
```